# Map display not filling window in QGIS on Mac?

Tags: qgis, mac, qgis-3

In this screenshot of QGIS, you can see that the map is not filling the window. I have tried resizing the window in various ways.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this a bug?

Versions:

- MacBook Pro MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5
- QGIS version 3.2.1-Bonn
- QGIS code branch Release 3.2
- Compiled against Qt 5.9.6
- Running against Qt 5.9.6
- Compiled against GDAL/OGR 2.2.4
- Running against GDAL/OGR 2.2.4
- Compiled against GEOS 3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2
- Running against GEOS 3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6
- PostgreSQL Client Version 9.6.6
- SpatiaLite Version 4.4.0-RC0
- QWT Version 6.1.3
- QScintilla2 Version 2.10.7
- PROJ.4 Version 493
- Python 3.6.6

[image: QGIS map not filling its window]

Comment: Is a bug, I have the same OS + QGIS 3.2.1 with the same problem. Earlier versions works fine

Comment: Thank you, same here with iMac 27 Retina.
Opening and arranging new window worked fine !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This is a bug](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19524). Install an earlier version or wait for it to be fixed.

Update: This Mac-specific bug brought attention to the fact that the QGIS has not been as well supported as for Windows as for MacOS. There is now a [MacOS specific bug fixing campaign](http://blog.qgis.org/2018/09/12/macosx-specific-bug-fixing-campaign/).

Comment: The newest release of QGIS always has bugs. If you're just learning to use this program you may want to stick with the LTR (long-term release) version, which is the most reliable version. I always keep two copies installed: the LTR and a more recent version.

Comment: List of earlier releases for macOS: https://qgis.org/downloads/macOS/

Comment: Thanks people. After I accepted csk's answer I did install the 2.18 version, and currently have both on my system. It wasn't initially clear to me that QGIS3 is a development version, in fact the site and the software itself is pushing for me to upgrade.

Comment: This [was addressed in 3.4.0](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19524#note-42).

Answer (score 22):

I have the same (OS X 10.11, Qgis 3.2.2). What I'm doing is opening a new map window (View / New Map View), anchoring it to the top or side edge, resizing it and closing it again. This causes the original window to return to its normal size. Works for me.[image]

Comment: Yep this seems to work

Comment: Resizing the Layers panel also works.

Comment: Nice workaround

Comment: Cool, it works for me as well - QGIS 3.2.2 and macOS 10.12.6. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have compiled QGIS with Macports.

> qgis3 3.2.1 (source) QGIS 3 is a user-friendly GIS based on Qt 5
>   Licenses: GPL-2+  Maintained by: vince atVeence openmaintainer
>   Categories: gis Platforms: darwin  Dependencies: cmake openssl
>   qt5-qtbase bison expat fcgi gdal geos grass7 gsl ld64 libiconv
>   libtasn1 libzip pkgconfig postgis2 postgresql10 proj py36-gdal
>   py36-jinja2 py36-owslib py36-psycopg2 py36-pygments py36-pyqt5
>   py36-qscintilla-qt5 py36-requests py36-sip py36-six py36-yaml python36
>   qca-qt5 qca-qt5-ossl qjson-qt5 qt5-qtscript qt5-qtscxml qt5-qtwebkit
>   qt5-qtxmlpatterns qt5-sqlite-plugin qtkeychain-qt5 qwt-qt5
>   spatialindex spatialite sqlite3  Variants: debug grass postgresql10
>   postgresql95 postgresql96 proj4 proj5 python34 python35 python36

The problem has been solved.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open any panel, resize it a little bit, then close it, the map view will be normal. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If I change the size of the layer panel, the problem goes away.

Same thing in a print layout, just change the size of the right side panel and it goes back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the panels, and the entire window, did the trick for me. A tad weird, but possibly the result of the version upgrade...important for me, as I have a 30" monitor, and I need to do big maps.

Answer (score 0):

A reported issue, no fix yet but a work-around, see:
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19545
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19524
Garth Fletcher