# Where to download qgis 3.0 for Mac to avoid the 3.2 bug?

Tags: qgis

So the editing function is great and all but I had to get a new laptop and installed this 3.2 which had the nasty bug of only using half the screen

To circumvent this I'd need to download 3.0 and it's not available on their web page. Is there like an alternate repository for Mac? On kingchaos page they only have up until 2.18

Comment: @luke you're right so how can I find it

Comment: If you want to use 3.2, there are a couple of workarounds for this bug: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/291656/81764

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download earlier releases from:

https://www.qgis.org/downloads/macOS/

For previous versions, check KyngChaos website:

https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive/#QGIS